# Nextflow: Specify Boot Image when using the Google Life Sciences API

Tags: nextflow

Is it possible in Nextflow to specify the boot image of the VM when using the Google Life Sciences API?
Specifically, I am talking about the `bootImage` parameter from here:
https://cloud.google.com/life-sciences/docs/reference/rest/v2beta/projects.locations.pipelines/run#virtualmachine

EDIT

The reason is the following: When I try to spawn a couple of workers that use GPUs, I get the following error message:

```
(more omitted..)
+ NVIDIA_DRIVER_VERSION=450.51.06
+ NVIDIA_DRIVER_MD5SUM=
+ NVIDIA_INSTALL_DIR_HOST=/var/lib/nvidia
+ NVIDIA_INSTALL_DIR_CONTAINER=/usr/local/nvidia
+ ROOT_MOUNT_DIR=/root
+ CACHE_FILE=/usr/local/nvidia/.cache
+ LOCK_FILE=/root/tmp/cos_gpu_installer_lock
+ LOCK_FILE_FD=20
+ set +x
[INFO    2021-02-24 18:27:39 UTC] PRELOAD: false
[INFO    2021-02-24 18:27:39 UTC] Running on COS build id 13310.1209.10
[INFO    2021-02-24 18:27:39 UTC] Data dependencies (e.g. kernel source) will be fetched from https://storage.googleapis.com/cos-tools/13310.1209.10
[INFO    2021-02-24 18:27:39 UTC] Getting the kernel source repository path.
[INFO    2021-02-24 18:27:39 UTC] Obtaining kernel_info file from https://storage.googleapis.com/cos-tools/13310.1209.10/kernel_info
[INFO    2021-02-24 18:27:40 UTC] Downloading kernel_info file from https://storage.googleapis.com/cos-tools/13310.1209.10/kernel_info

real    0m0.079s
user    0m0.014s
sys    0m0.004s
[INFO    2021-02-24 18:27:40 UTC] Checking if this is the only cos-gpu-installer that is running.
[INFO    2021-02-24 18:27:40 UTC] Checking if third party kernel modules can be installed
[INFO    2021-02-24 18:27:40 UTC] Checking cached version
[INFO    2021-02-24 18:27:40 UTC] Cache file /usr/local/nvidia/.cache not found.
[INFO    2021-02-24 18:27:40 UTC] Did not find cached version, building the drivers...
[INFO    2021-02-24 18:27:40 UTC] Downloading GPU installer ... 
[INFO    2021-02-24 18:27:40 UTC] Downloading from https://storage.googleapis.com/nvidia-drivers-eu-public/nvidia-cos-project/85/tesla/450_00/450.51.06/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.51.06_85-13310-1209-10.cos
[INFO    2021-02-24 18:27:40 UTC] Downloading GPU installer from https://storage.googleapis.com/nvidia-drivers-eu-public/nvidia-cos-project/85/tesla/450_00/450.51.06/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.51.06_85-13310-1209-10.cos

real    0m0.811s
user    0m0.175s
sys    0m0.495s
[INFO    2021-02-24 18:27:41 UTC] Setting up compilation environment
[INFO    2021-02-24 18:27:41 UTC] Obtaining toolchain_env file from https://storage.googleapis.com/cos-tools/13310.1209.10/toolchain_env
[INFO    2021-02-24 18:27:41 UTC] Downloading toolchain_env file from https://storage.googleapis.com/cos-tools/13310.1209.10/toolchain_env

real    0m0.021s
user    0m0.013s
sys    0m0.003s
[INFO    2021-02-24 18:27:41 UTC] Found toolchain path file locally
ls: cannot access '/build/cos-tools': No such file or directory
[INFO    2021-02-24 18:27:41 UTC] /build/cos-tools: 
ls: cannot access '/build/cos-tools': No such file or directory
[INFO    2021-02-24 18:27:41 UTC] Downloading toolchain from https://storage.googleapis.com/chromiumos-sdk/2020/06/x86_64-cros-linux-gnu-2020.06.25.065836.tar.xz
[INFO    2021-02-24 18:27:41 UTC] Downloading toolchain archive from https://storage.googleapis.com/chromiumos-sdk/2020/06/x86_64-cros-linux-gnu-2020.06.25.065836.tar.xz
curl: (16) Error in the HTTP2 framing layer

real    0m2.403s
user    0m0.580s
sys    0m1.461s
[ERROR   2021-02-24 18:27:44 UTC] Could not download toolchain archive from https://storage.googleapis.com/chromiumos-sdk/2020/06/x86_64-cros-linux-gnu-2020.06.25.065836.tar.xz, giving up.
```

So something about some toolchain that could not be found or installed. However, this issue occurs randomly. Sometimes I spawn 72 workers and everything is just fine. Sometimes I get this error.

I thought that changing the parameter I mentioned would resolve this issue, but you are right, it probably won't.

I did some digging but barely could not find anything related. The only somewhat related thread I could find is https://github.com/DataBiosphere/dsub/issues/215 , but there is also no solution posted.

Answer (score 1):

Not currently (as of v21.02.0-edge), see here:

https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/blob/v21.02.0-edge/plugins/nf-google/src/main/nextflow/cloud/google/lifesciences/GoogleLifeSciencesConfig.groovy

From the docs, it looks like the `bootImage` option has only a limited use case and probably doesn't make much sense for containerized workflows anyway:

> bootImage

> The host operating system image to use.
>
> Currently, only Container-Optimized OS images can be used.
>
> The default value is
> projects/cos-cloud/global/images/family/cos-stable, which selects the
> latest stable release of Container-Optimized OS.
>
> **This option is provided to allow testing against the beta release of
> the operating system to ensure that the new version does not interact
> negatively with production pipelines.**
>
> To test a pipeline against the beta release of Container-Optimized OS,
> use the value projects/cos-cloud/global/images/family/cos-beta.

Is there some reason you need a different boot image other than the latest stable release to run your workflow? A newer docker perhaps?

---

EDIT:

I've just had a look at the code I think is being run here, not sure if I've got the right version, but not sure if that really matters though:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cos-gpu-installer/blob/v20210204/cos-gpu-installer-docker/entrypoint.sh#L299-L324

I think the 'Could not download toolchain archive from ...' message is accurate and we see curl report: 'Error in the HTTP2 framing layer'. Why? I think it's just a download/timeout error if it occurs sporadically. Error in the HTTP2 framing layer is a bit weird though. I'm not sure what this means exactly and why using HTTP version 2 would be a problem sometimes. I think your best bet is to open an issue here:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cos-gpu-installer/issues

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. You correctly assumed that my problem is something different. I updated my question and added more details.

Comment: No worries @r0f1, thanks for the update. Please see my updated comments above. I also wonder if using [preemptible  instances](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/google.html#preemptible-instances) is a problem? Also, are you using the recommended process errorStrategy for preemptible instances?

Comment: I raised an issue over there. Let's see what happens. I am using preemptible instances and I am using the recommended error strategy (in fact, I encountered am also catching error codes 8 and 10, see https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/discussions/1913#discussioncomment-393563). But I am encountering this  issue also with non-preemptible machines, if I am not totally mistaken. I am definitely only encountering this with GPU machines.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Looks like they're considering forcing HTTP version 1.1. Hopefully that will fix it: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cos-gpu-installer/issues/69